# line-height working diffeerently for IE and chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, css

When i m typing text in input, the text cursor is working differenlty in chrome. For IE, it is appearing in center with text but for chrome, it is taking entire textbox height even though my font-size is 16px. When i m reducing line-height, then text is starting from top in IE.
Below is the css which i am using:

```
   .mainContent .searchBox .searchField .text
{float: left;width:507px ;height: 67px;
border:none;font-size: 16px;
font-family: verdana;color: #3F454F;
line-height: 4;}
```

Comment: A value of `4` should not even be honored. It needs to be `4px`. Why is your line-height so much smaller than your font size, anyway?

Comment: @Jeffman - `line-height:4` is valid. It means 4 times the font-size, not 4px.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your doc type is declared properly, if declared.

IE is iffy if the doc-type ain't correctly chosen.